# distributions in "A Note on the Inception Score"

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, conditional-probability, gan

I'm reading the following paper [A Note on the Inception Score](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01973.pdf). IS is a evaluation metric for GAN. While reading the paper I got very confused about the notation of so called distributions.

I will first list a few other questions that seem to relevant but do not completely answer my questions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058029/probability-distribution-and-data-distribution-in-ml
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54346/data-generating-probability-distribution-probability-distribution-of-a-dataset
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26009/what-does-it-mean-for-the-training-data-to-be-generated-by-a-probability-distrib/54342#54342

In section 3 we can find this statement

> Suppose we are trying to evaluate a trained generative model
> G that encodes a distribution $p_g$ over images x. We can
> sample from $p_g$ as many times as we would like, but do
> not assume that we can directly evaluate $p_g$.

And then in section 3.2

> where x ∼ $p_g$ indicates that x is an image sampled from $p_g$,
> $D_{KL}(p ||q)$ is the KL-divergence between the distributions
> $p$ and $q$, $p(y|x)$ is the conditional class distribution, and $p(y) =\int_x p(y|x)p_g(x)$ is the marginal class distribution.

**1.** The first question picks up a question from https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54346/data-generating-probability-distribution-probability-distribution-of-a-dataset: What does $p_g(x)$ mean in plain english?

I get that it is a data distribution, and we **can sample from it**. And given that x is a generated image by G, how does it fit together with $p_g(x)$

- Can it also be "What is the probability that the generated sample x does indeed came from $p_g$"
- or is it the likelihood that x was produced by $p_g$
- etc.

**2.** Then we have **conditional class distribution $p(y|x)$**. I have a hard time visualizing this in my head. My guess is that is probably means $p(Y=y|X=x)$, so we have 2 random variables and $y$ is the class label and $x$ is an image. How would I plot such information? If I just have $p(Y=y)$ where y is the class information one can easily visualize this distribution. Is the same possible for $p(y|x)$?

**3.** The formula for $p(y)$ is given by $p(y) =\int_x p(y|x)p_g(x)$. Earlier it is said that we

> but do not assume that we can directly evaluate $p_g$

So what does $p_g(x)$ refers to in this case? And what does $\int_x$ refers to in this case? Can you give an example?(maybe the probability of class $2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure what the confusion is about $p_g$ — it's the probability distribution of images produced by generator $G$. We generally assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is an image tensor, so you can think of $p_g$ as some probability density function with pixel-space support (e.g., over $\mathbb{R}^{\text{height} \times \text{width} \times \text{channels}}$). It has nothing to do with $P(\mathbf{x}\text{ came from G})$; it is simply the distribution of images encoded by $G$.
   The [original GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf) might also give you more insight on what $p_g$ actually is -- in practice, to sample from $p_g$, we might do $\mathbf{x} \sim G(\mathbf{z})$ where $\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ (or some other distribution).
2. I don't usually think of $p(y | \mathbf{x})$ as a "thing to plot," but rather from a classification perspective. In the context of this paper, $p(y \mid \mathbf{x})$ is InceptionNet's estimate of the probability that image $\mathbf{x}$ belongs to class $y$ (i.e., that $\mathbf{x}$ is an image of $y$).  I'm not familiar with ways to plot the entire conditional distribution, but you could visualize the multinomial distribution of $y$ given a single image $\mathbf{x}$ pretty easily (i.e., P(y = class | x) for the most "likely" classes).
3. We do not need the explict form of $p_g$ to estimate $p(y)$, as demonstrated in Eq. 5. I am not sure what the confusion is about $\int_x$ — it's the integral taken over the support of $p_g$ (i.e., pixel-space). An equivalent way to write that integral (that leads directly to Eq. 5) is $\int_x p(y \mid \mathbf{x}) p_g(\mathbf{x}) dx = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x} \sim p_g}[p(y \mid \mathbf{x})]$, which follows from the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: I guess the question was a little misleading. But the answers did help me. I think my main point is that I read about $p_g(x)$ (which indicates to me I can plugin a $x$ ) and $x$ is a sample generated by G then what does the result of $p_g(x)$ tell me?

Comment: "The result" of the expression $p_g(x)$ is just the PDF of the image distribution evaluated at $x$. So, it tells you exactly the same things as any other density; e.g., relative likelihood, or how many times more likely is image $x$ in distribution $G$ vs. image $x'$. If it helps, pretend that $p_g(x)$ is a Gaussian PDF for the sake of example. But I don't think the properties of PDFs are super relevant/essential to understanding this paper (though I've only skimmed).

Comment: yeah true thats unrelated, I have accepted the answer, thanks!